# How can I show that a set is dense in $\mathbb{R}?$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Excuse me, the problem is: 
If $u>0$ is any number and $x<y$, show that exists $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $$x<ru<y.$$

I know that the problem is show that $\{ru:r\in\mathbb{Q},u>0\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. I had tried with the archimedean property, and other thing but I can't do it. I feel mentally blocket.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes!!!, in fact, if I take in count that, the only case that have to show is when $u$ is irrational.

Comment: Ok, I feel so fool

Answer (score 1):

You want to find a rational number between $\frac{x}{u}$ and $\frac{y}{u}.$